# How we retrieve the 'tags' and 'attachment' of the custom post which is created by wp_insert_post();

Tags: terms

I am not able to get the data of post which i inserted by

```
wp_insert_post();
```

now i want to get the tags which i stored by

```
'tags_input' => array('thread_tag' => $tags)
```

and i also upload an image of this post as attachment, so could you please tell me  how to retrieve the attachment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
```

to get the `ID` of the inserted post. You can try this:

```
   $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'thread_tag');
```

to get the terms from your post with `$post_id`. You can check out the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

You can then use `get_children()`

```
$args = array(
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_parent' => $post_id,
'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );
```

to fetch the attachments for this post. More on the Codex page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

**Edit:**

To set the terms in the `'thread_tag'` taxonomy for a given `$post_id`

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id,array('term1','term2'),'thread_tag');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms